# How do I format tshark time to ISO format (yyyy-dd-mm)?

Tags: wireshark, tshark, time-format

I'm trying to print out various fields from a PCAP containing HTTP traffic. One of the columns should be the timestamp in the ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD hhmmss).

Also, if anyone has a full list of fields that work under -e, that would be awesome (eg, ip.src, frame.time, etc).

Just as an example, I'm starting from a couple angles:

```
tshark -r out.pcap -R "tcp.port==80" -o column.format:"Packet,%m,Time,%t,Info%i" 

tshark -r out.pcap -R "tcp.port==80" -T fields -e frame.time
```

Answer (score 9):

Did you try the following:

```
tshark -r out.pcap -R "tcp.port==80" -o column.format:"Packet,%m,Time,%Yt,Info,%i"
```

... or the more modern versions as either:

```
tshark -r out.pcap -2R "tcp.port==80" -o gui.column.format:"Packet,%m,Time,%Yt,Info,%i"
```

or:

```
tshark -r out.pcap -Y "tcp.port==80" -o gui.column.format:"Packet,%m,Time,%Yt,Info,%i"
```

The key there is to use `%Yt` instead of `%t`, which uses `YYYY-MM-DD hhmmss.` format.  If you want UTC, then use `%Yut`.  Other formats are available as well.

Note that:

Prior to Wireshark commit [r52627](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/blob/63e4539229ca54fe44abc84745099c0e4f1a7c8e/tshark.c) to resolve [Wireshark Issue 9272 - column format strings are only documented in source code](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/issues/9272), the column formats were only documented in the source code itself (i.e., in [epan/column.c](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/blob/master/epan/column.c)); however, after that revision, you can run `tshark -G column-formats` to view them.

(That revision is only currently available in the development version of Wireshark though.  Regardless, you can still use the source code itself as a reference.  If you'd like to download the development release, visit the [Wireshark download page](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html).)

To answer your second inquiry, namely *"if anyone has a full list of fields that work under -e, that would be awesome"*, you can refer to the [Wireshark display filter reference page](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/).  Basically, any named field can be used.